# Need help on Java 1.8 Optional with map

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, option-type

I want to check the string object, if exists return one object or else return another one.

When the condition executes, it is not returning and continues to else execution also.

```
return Optional.of(where.getObject()).filter(f -> f.isPresent()).map(str -> {
    System.out.println("Value here is str" + str.get());
    return getPredicateByOption(joinMap.get(str.get()), where, builder, null);
}).orElse(getPredicateByOption(null, where, builder, root));
```

I'm trying to replace the following `if` condition:

```
if (!Optional.empty().equals(where.getObject())) 
     return getPredicateByOption(null, where, builder, root); 
return getPredicateByOption(joinMap.get(where.getObject().get()), where, builder, null);
```

The return type of `where.getObject()` is `Optional<String>`.

Comment: What does `where.getObject` and `getPredicateByOption` do?

Comment: getObject returns string. getPredicateOption returns Predicate.

Comment: I was trying to replacing below if condition. `if (!Optional.empty().equals(where.getObject()))
   return getPredicateByOption(null, where, builder, root);

  return getPredicateByOption(joinMap.get(where.getObject().get()), where, builder, null);`

Comment: You mean `getObject` returns a `Optional<String>` am I right?

Comment: getObject Yes and getPredicateOption will not return Optional<Predicate>

Comment: I know it's hard when you don't give us a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). Is the `sysout` getting printed?

Comment: Based on the first sentence of your question, you ought to be using a simple `if .. else` statement, or a ternary operator.  Using Java 8's snazzy new functional operations just because they're snazzy isn't good practice.  In this case, using the boring old syntax that's been around since C would undoubtedly lead to more readable code that has a better chance of working.

Comment: `Optional.empty().equals(…)` is a very twisted way of saying `… .isEmpty()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `if` condition can be replaced in the following way:

```
return getPredicateByOption(where.getObject().map(joinMap::get).orElse(null), 
                            where, builder, 
                            where.getObject().isPresent() ? null : root);
```

I assume that `where.getObject()` returns an `Optional<String>` which holds the key from the `joinMap` map. Note that even if `where.getObject` returns non-empty optional, but the corresponding string is absent in `joinMap`, you will still get the correct result (first argument passed to `getPredicateByOption` will be null.